# OpenGL blurry RAW file

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I am mapping a very large background texture to a quad for a sidescroller. The texture's graphics do not have any aliasing, and therein lies the problem.

The texture ends up very blurry. The image size is 800 x 600. Do the dimensions have to be a power of 2? If so, Am I stuck making a larger image at 1024 x 1024 and leaving the excess offscreen?

I am doing everything in orthographic mode. Here is the application of the texture to quad.

```
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, *texture); 

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(pos_x, pos_y, depth);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(pos_x + size_x, pos_y, depth);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(pos_x + size_x, pos_y + size_y, depth);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(pos_x, pos_y + size_y, depth);
    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
```

Comment: Please show us how you output your texture to screen. What perspective do you use, how do you map the texture to polygons? Maybe some relevant code quotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you need to disable mipmap filtering when creating your texture:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```